# How can we demonstrate a Swiss Visitor will go home? (appealing Visa refusal)

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

I know there have been many questions asked about rejected visas.
However, every single case is a bit different, and I now need your help to sort something out with the visa.

I'm a Swiss citizen. My fiancé is Egyptian. He wanted to come here in August for a visit for the first time, however he got his Visitor Visa refused.
We are now considering doing an appeal, however we're in a very bad position, because my fiancé's final goal would be immigrating to Switzerland in the future. But not this time. This time it was really only about visiting and seeing the country.
A few facts:

- the reasons the visa was refused were:

  > The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.
  >
  > Your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of visa could not be ascertained.
- the purpose of the travel was stated on the invitation letter that my mother signed, and were: visiting my family and visiting Switzerland
- on the invitation letter we also stated the following:

  - Details of my mom and of my fiancé
  - Period of the trip: from the end of July to the end of August 2015
  - relationship: family friend since 4 years (we left out the fact that he's my fiancé thinking that it would lead to a direct refusal)
  - guarantee of his return: a short paragraph stating that after the visit he would return to Egypt
  - costs of the trip: we stated that we would offer accommodation in our house and food during the stay, saying that my mom is self funded and has enough money for that (we also brought the bank statement, but it wasn't taken at the time of delivery)
  - Passport copy attached
- my fiancé delivered all the papers requested (application form, passport, certificate from Mogamma, identity photo, invitation letter, employment certificate, confirmation of leave approval, bank statement, insurance, round trip flight ticket)

After delivering all the papers, we don't really understand what went wrong.

Anyhow, what happened, happened, and now we want to make an appeal. We read some info online, and found that basically what we need is to show that he has strong ties to his country. Which he doesn't. He has a job, yeah, but he's looking for a new one (in Egypt or in Europe), as the contract is ending. He's not responsible for anyone (such as children) in Egypt. He would like to immigrate in the near future.

So at this point, other than the letter from my mom saying that we guarantee that he would return to the country, we really don't have much.

What could we deliver with the appeal to make them understand that it's really just a visit? Because it is, we're not planning to break the rules and make him stay with an expired visa. We just want him to come, spend some quality time with us in this beautiful country, and then let him go back to Egypt till the next time.

Comment: The issue is that he doesn't have anything that ties him back to Egypt and for some reason a mother of a girl is sponsoring his trip.  You've just raised red flags galore and waived them around.

Comment: Red flags or not, it doesn't seem right that for that reason a honest person that wants to visit is not allowed to. Doesn't respect human rights much in my opinion. 

The fact that he doesn't have very strong ties in Egypt basically means that he will not allowed to go to another country because they're afraid that he will stay there illegally, hence he's stuck in Egypt until we get married (which we don't wanna do for the purpose of getting the visa) or finds a job here (which again is very hard because they hire people from the EEA zone before they go and get someone from Egypt)

Comment: `honest person that wants to visit is not allowed to` That is what you think. Think from the visa officer's point of view. He(she) needs evidence to see he is a genuine visitor. There are cases where fraudulent people have used the fiance/marriage route to emigrate illegally to EU countries, so the visa oficer is being a little cautious.

Comment: @tita So why don't you visit him?

Comment: @tita The long story short you intend to get married and he will be joining you in Switzerland, rather then you joining him in Egypt.  They are not afraid that he will stay in Switzerland illegally.  They are afraid that the purpose of his visit isn't a visit, which as you have described it isn't.  So from the perspective of the immigration officer who is supposed to determine whether or not the potential visitor is lying on his application how does a mother of an unattached daughter inviting a unattached man to her home sound?

Comment: @Karlson I know how it sounds, but it isn't as it sounds, he's really just coming for a visit to see the country for the first time, there's no intention at all of staying here on the visa we're trying to get. That will come later, once we decide to get married.
The question here is, how to convince them that it's not as it sounds? Not possible? Then there's something wrong. Shouldn't a honest person have the right to visit another country where his friends live?

Comment: @tita The simplest way is to have reason for him to leave, such as a job, a family(meaning wife and kids), a business, or something similar.  There is no question about rights to visit there are agreements between countries about visitors that's why borders exist.  You have the right to visit him obtaining visa on arrival.  But you choose not to exercise it.  And for the immigration officer there is no reason to look beyond exactly what it appears to be from the documentation you have submitted which basically implies that you 2 want to get married and that's an entirely different visa.

Comment: @Karlson I have visited him many times in Egypt, and this time we wanted to exchange the roles, so that he can see my country as well and meet the rest of my family. 
We don't want to get married now, but how can we prove that?
Right now he's working in a company in Egypt, but with the visa papers he also delivered the leave approval from his boss. I don't know what to give them more than this

Comment: @tita And therein lies the problem.  You have nothing else to give.  I would suggest contacting an immigration lawyer to help you with this but long story short as it stand you have no documentary proof that he will leave the country.

Comment: @tita, I don't get the part about 'honest person'.  He depicts himself as a long-standing friend of the family when he is really just your fiance; and he has shrouded the principal agenda of his visit, which is to maintain the relationship with his fiance.  That would seem to forfeit his claim to being an honest person, but you do not think so.  I don't get it.

Comment: @GayotFow he is not just my fiancé. For the past 4 years he's been in touch with the rest of my family as well, my mother has visited him and his family in Egypt as well. My whole family considers him part of the family already, therefore I'm sure that beside me considering him my fiancé, the rest of my family considers him a friend. So I don't know what's wrong with that.